# How to divide the dataset into different groups and generate a variable with the group name

Tags: r, loops

I have created a dataset of 10.000 observations with 2 randomly generated variables. Now, I want to divide these 10.000 observations into 100 groups and generate a variable with the `group_number` and `group_id`.

What I have done so far-

```
csize = 100  # number of clusters
n = 10000    # number of observations in each cluster 
p = 2        # number of variables 

# Generating matrix with 100 normally distributed values for each p
set.seed(1)
mydata = matrix(rnorm(n*p, mean=0, sd = 1), n, p)
```

Now, I want to divide these observations into 100 clusters (each cluster having 100 observations), then add two variables: `cluster_name` and `group_id`. Under the variable `cluster_name`, I would like to put on `cluster_1, ..., cluster_100`, and within each cluster, I would like to generate `group_id` for the observations.

Thanks in advance for your kind help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done all in one shot like so:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(
    cluster_name = rep(paste0("cluster_",1:100), each=100),
    group_id     = rep(1:100, each=100),
    var1         = rnorm(10000),
    var2         = rnorm(10000),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

We can then look at the first/last rows of the dataframe:

```
head(df)
#  cluster_name group_id       var1       var2
#1   cluster_1        1 -0.6264538 -0.8043316
#2   cluster_1        1  0.1836433 -1.0565257
#3   cluster_1        1 -0.8356286 -1.0353958
#4   cluster_1        1  1.5952808 -1.1855604
#5   cluster_1        1  0.3295078 -0.5004395
#6   cluster_1        1 -0.8204684 -0.5249887

tail(df)
#      cluster_name group_id      var1       var2
#9995  cluster_100      100 0.2096655 -0.1536432
#9996  cluster_100      100 0.9595076  1.5789764
#9997  cluster_100      100 0.4366036 -0.8131629
#9998  cluster_100      100 0.4993666  0.2795815
#9999  cluster_100      100 0.8939798 -1.2650635
#10000 cluster_100      100 0.2573871  0.5041590
```

Comment: Dear Dan Y,
This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!!